# Some items have coordinates switched when loading PostGIS layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am having problem with strange coordinates switching when loading PostGIS layers in QGIS. First, I thought, that problem may be cause by the use of `GROUP_BY` feature in layer query, but later the problem started to appear in other queries not using this feature and finally it happens also with single table actually containing the geometry multilinestring data (with srid 4326). The problem sometimes strangely disappear when local copy of the sama data (shapefile) is already loaded.

When the problem appears, coordinates of some items are switched, like this:

Correct: `LINESTRING(16.87593599289347779 49.7559793078007857, ...`
Switched:`LINESTRING(49.7559793078007857 16.87593599289347779, ...`

The data themselves are fine, because if I export table to shapefile, all coordinates are correct. I tried to look at PostgreSQL log (all statements are logged) but no errors were found.

I am using:

- PostgreSQL 9.1
- PostGIS 2.1 (full version "POSTGIS="2.1.0 r11822" GEOS="3.3.3-CAPI-1.7.4" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009" GDAL="GDAL 1.9.0, released 2011/12/29" LIBXML="2.8.0" TOPOLOGY RASTER")
- QGIS 2.4

EDIT:
Some further observations:

- problem appears when I add multiple PostgreSQL layers to QGIS. Some
  of the objects become "switched" instantly. The other layer usually
  brake after I remove the first one from the view (same "switching
  behavior").
- problem also appears when I try to create virtual layer
  in QGIS DB manager plugin (in most simple cases such as table with
  spatial column loaded twice - once through PostGIS layers dialog,
  once through DB manager
- There also seems to be another related issue, which is likely different, because when the features can't be seen, they can still be selected. In this case, "switching" happens on reload (or zoom). On another one, lines appear correctly, only to disappear again on another reload.

Also, the problem appeared on PostGIS 2.0 ("POSTGIS="2.0.1 r9979" GEOS="3.3.3-CAPI-1.7.4" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.9.0, released 2011/12/29" LIBXML="2.7.8" TOPOLOGY RASTER")

To help understand my issue better, I created screencast at http://youtu.be/rqS6kaFfUaQ

Comment: That's odd. I use PostGIS and QGIS a lot and have never seen such a behavior. Can you provide a mini database dump which shows this behavior? If we can't reproduce the problem, this is going to be hard to answer.

Comment: Sure. I will try to set up the local environment, copy the data and provide relevant part of the log.

Comment: I managed to replicate the error, see edited answer.

Comment: I updated the question with some further observations.

Comment: I created screencast showing the issue at http://youtu.be/rqS6kaFfUaQ

Comment: If you have to pick the CRS when loading a table from PostGIS, then the table is not correctly configured in the database. Note that you did not have to pick a CRS for the first table you added.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not source of the issue, because it happens also with other layers, where I don't need to specify CRS on load. But it appears, that the issue is not present when using PostgreSQL 2.3. I am testing it further.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that issue is solved simply by upgrading DB to PostgreSQL 9.3.